# PHP smtp Startup Error in apache log file while restarting the wamp server on windows 2012

Tags: wamp, windows-server-2012

I have enabled 'smtp' PHP extension. Wamp restarted automatically and throwing the below error in apache error log file. When ever we are start or restarting wamp same error is repeating.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: smtp: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20060613\nPHP    compiled with module API=20100525\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

Can you please suggest why this error is coming?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running? Also Apache and PHP versions?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.snmp.php) Getting the SNMP extension up and running is not a click and go process.

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly, Please find versions below,
Wampserver -- 2.4,
PHP -- 5.4.16
Apache -- 2.4.4

Comment: Looks like the `snmp` extension is compiled with a different version of MSVC to the PHP and Apache. You may have to find another version of `php_snmp` which is compiled with MSVC 2010

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly, I didn't enabled the "php_snmp" extension in wampserver.